# Using a subclass method on a base class object

Tags: c#

Let's say I have declared the following classes:

```
class BaseClass{
    /* properties, constructors, getters, setters etc. */

    public static BaseClass Create(string url){
    /*will return, depending on url, a BaseClass or a SubClass object*/
    }

    public void Method(){
    /* some code here */
    }
}

class SubClass: BaseClass{
    /* other properties, constructors, getters, setters etc. */

    new public void Method(){
    /* some other code here */
    }
}
```

Now in my Main method I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
BaseClass baseClass = BaseClass.Create(url);
if(baseClass.GetType()==typeof(SubClass)){ 
    baseClass.Method();
}
```

The idea here, of course, is to use `Method` as it is implemented in `SubClass`. It may be a silly question but how do I do that? I can't cast a base class into a subclass so I'm not sure...

### **EDIT**

Clarified my question. Even though baseClass was declared as a BaseClass instance, `baseClass is SubClass` will return `true`if `url` is such that `Create` returns a `SubClass` instance.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If you've created a `new BaseClass`, it will never be `typeof(SubClass)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be looking for polymorphism, but I can't be sure from the description.  What is the concrete use case for what you're trying to do?

```
class BaseClass{

    public virtual void Method(){
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass{
    /* other properties, constructors, getters, setters etc. */

    public override void Method(){
        Console.WriteLine("SubClass");
    }
}

static class Test
{
    public void go() {
        BaseClass instance = new SubClass();
        instance.Method(); // prints "SubClass"
    }
}
```

If it doesn't make sense for the base class to have an implementation, then [declare the class and the method as abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) -- this forces the derived classes to override the method, guaranteeing that any instantiated class instance will have a valid implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know why you would want to do that?

There is no way that the type of an instance of `BaseClass` will be equal to the type of `SubClass`.
That could only be possible if you created a instance of `SubClass` and then cast it to `BaseClass`. But in that case you could just cast it back to `SubClass` to call `Method()`

Answer (score 1):

If you instansiate the `baseClass` as `BaseClass` you will not be able to call the method as `SubClass`, but if you write

```
BaseClass baseClass = new SubClass();
if (baseClass is SubClass)
{
    SubClass subClass = baseClass as SubClass;
    subClass.Method();
}
```

it will call the method as the `SubClass` is defined.

Comment: `as` is almost the same as a regular cast, the only difference is that it doesn't raise an exception if the cast is invalid, it leaves a null-reference instead. It is okay in this example, but with more complex code, I would check for `null` after the cast.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the tip! After reading more about virtual methods I realized they are in fact the right way to go in my case. It seems a far more elegant solution since no explicit test is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you have to initialise your variable as an instance of `SubClass`, otherwise there is no way.

Then declare the method in the base class `virtual`,

or

cast the object to `SubClass`, and call the Method that way.

So either

```
class BaseClass{
    /* properties, constructors, getters, setters etc. */

    virtual public void Method(){
    /* some code here */
    }
}
```

or

```
 ((SubClass)baseClass).Method();
```

Comment: that won't work since the baseClass object is instanciated as BaseClass. You would get a invalid cast exception...

Comment: Oh.. right - didn't read carefully enough :). But then wouldn't it mean that `baseClass.GetType()==typeof(SubClass)` would always result in `false`?